# Are there any tools to go from ERD to DB design and vice versa?

Tags: mysql, database-design, schema, tools, erd

I'm learning DB design and looking for some tools, preferably open source software, that could help go from an ERD to a DATABASE and vice versa.

For the record, the database i'm using is MySQL.

Comment: Sybase's Power Designer is the tool I used, but only in ED -> DB direction.  The opposite is less than satisfactory.

Comment: @joe A bit late to say this, but: **Welcome to DBA.SE**! You might notice that your original question has been slightly edited for clarity. If you haven't done so already, please read the [FAQ](http://dba.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: I use DrawERD https://help.drawerd.com/

Answer (score 5):

Since you're using MySQL, you might want to take a look at [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/).

It *might* not quite display the ERDs you're expecting but it gets the job done.

And it does have an import feature. I have only used it to import SQL files but apparently you can import from existing MySQL databases.

---

Also, a long time ago I found the following tools; but were not quite useful to me back then (perhaps they've matured by now):

- [Database Design Tool - DDT](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/solution/database-design-tool-for-database-developers/)
- [Mogwai ERDesigner](http://mogwai.sourceforge.net/erdesignerng.html)

Comment: cool, what i'm looking for is a designer GUI style, like Visual Studio's in which you can add entities...

Answer (score 3):

I know of [ERWin](http://erwin.com/), though we don't use it at our company. We tend to "bleed blue" (ie, use IBM), so we use [InfoSphere Data Architect](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/optim/data-architect/).

Ideas for paid products anyway....

You could also check out [IBM Data Studio](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/optim/data-studio/) as its free. I believe it does ER to DDL and it supports more than just IBM databases.

Answer (score 0):

Generate ERD with PHPMyAdmin is also a better option. PHPMyadmin added this functionality from version 3.4

detail step to generate ERD : http://goo.gl/0z3vFE

You can refer to PHPMyAdmin documentation for more info: http://www.phpmyadmin.net/documentation/#pmadb

Comment: When linking to your own website, you should note that in your answer, otherwise this might be considered spam.